# С помощью библиотеки shutil не могу скопировать файлы из словаря в папку

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil, копирование

В своей функции с помощью **shutil.copy2** я пытаюсь скопировать файлы из словаря в созданные уже мною папки, но получаю исключение:

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'icons/actions/address-book-new.png'**

Нахожусь я сейчас в папке, в которую нужно скопировать файл. В данный момент **file = 'icons/actions/address-book-new.png'**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```
dict_year = {2017: {5: ['icons/status/weather-snow.png'],
                    6: ['icons/status/mail-attachment.png']}, 
             2018: {1: ['icons/status/semi-starred.png'],
                    2: ['icons/status/trophy-bronze.png']}}

def copy_files(dict_year):
    new_path = 'icons_by_year'
    os.mkdir(new_path)
    os.chdir(new_path)
    for year, value in dict_year.items():
        os.mkdir(str(year))
        os.chdir(str(year))
        for month, file_list in value.items():
            os.mkdir(str(month))
            os.chdir(str(month))
            for file in file_list:
                shutil.copy2(file, os.getcwd())
            os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
        os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код нормально

Comment: "Нахожусь я сейчас в папке, в которую нужно скопировать файл", а директория icons где находится?

Comment: и os.chdir изменит директорию в которой ты находишься. это важно)

Comment: если тебе позарез нужно ченджить директорию, то прежде чем начать работу сделай все пути в словаре абсолютными.

Comment: Поддержу @alex - относительные пути при работе с разными каталогами могут неправильно резолвится. Приведите все к абсолютным путям и, скорее всего, ошибка уйдёт. Ну или на крайний случай вы её явно увидите

Comment: @alex структура директорий такая: первичная рабочая директория - в ней **icons**, **icons_by_year/2017/5** (путь куда нужно скопировать файл) тоже находится в первичной рабочей директории. По ходу кода я захожу в папку месяца (**5**) и делаю ее рабочей, откуда и вызываю **shutil.copy2**

Comment: к абсолютному пути привести не могу, потому что пишу в гите, код не сработает на другом компьютере.